# Where is MONO IDE and how to install

Tags: mono, monodevelop

From where I can download MONO IDE. I have been using visual studio for years but never used MONO.

Now I have been given a task to create .net project in MONO enviorment. I need step by step installation guide. I need GUI based IDE for this.

I have visited mono develop website but didn't get any help.

Comment: [The MonoDevelop website](https://www.monodevelop.com) have a [download](https://www.monodevelop.com/download/) link at the top. There you will be told what you need to do for macOS, Linux or Windows. For Windows it's more job as there's no pre-build installer, for Linux there's some work, and for macOS there's a button for downloading Visual Studio, unless you want to build from source (as for Windows).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thank you. I basically need it on the windows platform and like the visual studio is there any IDE where I can compile and debug code in a MONO environment.

Comment: As I recall, it should be possible to configure VS to use any suitable .NET environment. That aside, do you really *need* to? One of the main points of .NET is that it shouldn't be platform dependent. If you build a C# program (for example) the executable should be possible to run on any system which have a suitable .NET environment, no matter if it's Mono's or Microsofts. So please [edit] your question to be more specific with your requirements and limitations.

Comment: MonoDevelop is no longer an active project, https://blog.lextudio.com/the-end-of-monodevelop-80b383dab34b and even Mono is going away, https://blog.lextudio.com/the-end-of-mono/ So what you should consider is whether that task given to you is reasonable and worth the while.